# Generation of nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

Does anyone know a better way get the output generated by this code:

```
Table[Table[{b-a,b},{b,7}]{a,7}]
```

Comment: Try `Table[{b - a, b}, {a, 7}, {b, 7}]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Or without using `Table` or any variable names: `Outer[{#2 - #1, #2} &, Range[7], Range[7]]`